# What does Genie babble in German?

Tags: dialogue, aladdin

When Genie turns into a submarine to save Aladdin, he "babbles something in German". Or atleast that's what a couple of the scripts say:

- https://www.slideshare.net/rpkarthigan/aladdin-script
- http://www.fpx.de/fp/Disney/Scripts/Aladdin.txt

Does anyone know exactly what he babbles?

For reference, here is the scene:

Comment: It is called *grammelot*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammelot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing sensical. It's babbling. Literally, the subtitles in the DVD say

> (babbling in the German language)

Nothing he says is actual German. He's just making it up, stringing along german sounding sounds.

Comment: Cheers for your answer!